# What is the difference between a CornerstoneJS viewport and an image object?

Tags: javascript, cornerstonejs

[CornerstoneJS](https://www.cornerstonejs.org/) is a JavaScript library for displaying medical images in web browsers. We are [using this tool](https://github.com/MIMBCD-UI/prototype-cornerstone) within our [Deep Learning (DL)](https://medium.com/oppr/using-cornerstonejs-and-orthanc-to-support-deep-learning-projects-c9675819c33a) projects, and have some specific questions. The [CornerstoneJS documentation](https://docs.cornerstonejs.org/) does not provide a clear relationship between the [`viewports`](https://docs.cornerstonejs.org/concepts/viewports.html) and the [`image`](https://docs.cornerstonejs.org/api.html#image) object.

In addition, the [`viewports`](https://docs.cornerstonejs.org/concepts/viewports.html) can be created by simply:

```
const element = document.createElement('div');

document.body.appendChild(element);

const viewport = cornerstone.getDefaultViewportForImage(element, image);

cornerstone.displayImage(element, image, viewport);
```

On the contrary, the [`image`](https://docs.cornerstonejs.org/api.html#image) object can be defined by:

```
var imageId = 'https://example.com/image.dcm';
var image = new conerstone.Image();

image.imageId = imageId;
```

Therefore, the following question arises:

**What is the difference between a CornerstoneJS viewport and an image object?**

We tried to understand the particular use cases to use an `image` object with and without the `viewports` of the CornerstoneJS library. From here, we could not understand the benefits of using the CornerstoneJS `viewports` instead of using the `image` object only with our self-developed "`viewports`" option. Therefore, we would like to understand the relationship between both of them so that we could consider using them instead our solution.